# Validating throwaway forms not related to a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

I have a form which takes in data, but it is not stored in any model. Instead, it is used to perform calculations and modify a model.  Is there any way I can validate the data on the form (for example, forcing certain inputs to be of integer form) within rails, and without writing it manually in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the rails mantra of "keep your controllers skinny", you should put your validations in your models. However you are stating that this data isn't backed by a database. This is ok, since you can create objects that act like a model(which means you can still have the activerecord validations in there).

I would highly suggest reading Yehuda Katz's post on [ActiveModel: Make Any Ruby Object Feel Like ActiveRecord](http://ActiveModel%3a%20Make%20Any%20Ruby%20Object%20Feel%20Like%20ActiveRecord). From there you can use the ActiveRecord validations that you've been used to!